# Use compass in gem for rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, external, compass-sass

I'm trying to create a gem which represents a JS and CSS library and can be included in rails projects (currently using 3.2). All the style sheets are written in SASS and depend on the **compass** library.

I tried adding `compass-rails` to the Gemfile of the "external" gem and including it in the gems SASS files using

```
@import "compass"
```

However, back in the rails application (which has a dependency to this gem), this results in an error message:

```
File to import not found or unreadable: compass.
```

Am I doing something wrong?

**Update:** It seems to work if I add `gem compass-rails` to the `Gemfile` of the rails application. Any change to work around that?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Did you follow the manual? https://github.com/Compass/compass-rails/#upgrading-existing-rails-projects-using-compass-to-compassrails

Comment: Yes, I did. But what does it tell me about using compass in an external gem?

Comment: By the way, tried to do exactly the same with the `bourbon` library...same issue there.

Answer (score 1):

Besides adding compass-rails to the Gemfile of the gem, you also need to `require 'compass-rails'` somewhere, adding it to `lib/your_gem_name.rb` inside the gem worked for me.